# Google App Engine and win32 DDE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pywin32, dde

I'm trying to set up a little server through the App Engine Python development server:

GOAL:
On Windows I've got a DDE application.
I need to read data from this application and serve it over the Internet.

SITUATION:
The development server is working correctly on port 80, enabling me to store data and make it available as JSON over the Internet.

PROBLEM:
I cannot get the development server to work correctly with the `win32` Python library.
I enabled the module in the local whitelist, but still when trying to start a DDE connection it says:

```
This must be an MFC application - try loading win32ui first 
      args = ('This must be an MFC application - try loading win32ui first',) 
      message = 'This must be an MFC application - try loading win32ui first'
```

I have got no idea on what to do. Any hint will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not on the GAE development server: I managed to uninstall the win32 python build 216 library and install a previous version. The problem was indeed with the manifest of the build 216 and not with the GAE development server. Now it works fine with build 214.